# What meaning is the word "as" in this sentence?

Tags: as

There is a sentence in my test paper:

> Sometimes, bullying is an Internet event,__when someone puts mean words about you on Facebook.
>
> (A)as (B)such (C)so (D)as if

The answer is (A),but I don't have any idea still even after I saw the answer.
Can someone explain this "as" for me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Like many small words of Anglo-Saxon derivation, 'as' has many different uses in English. It is commonly used when comparing things (e.g. 'this is not as big as that'). In this case it is being used to further explain the clause that precedes it, 'bullying is an Internet event'. 'As', in this case, could be replaced with 'for example', 'for instance' or even 'such as'.

Comment: Thanks for your help first. According to your example"this is not as big as that",I know the former"as" is  served as an adverb and the latter "as" is used as a conjunction. However, I'm confused about whether the "as" in the topic is an adverb or a conjunction. After all, the definitions of"as" in Oxford dictionary are mostly adverbs or conjunctions. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/as